# Encoding error reading stata file,read_stata() does not accept encoding argument python

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

first I tried simply reading the file

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_stata('filename.dta')
```

and it returned the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 68: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried adding a encoding argument such as `'latin'`, `'iso8859-1'` but it then returns the following error

```
TypeError: read_stata() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

checking the documentation for `pandas 1.0.1` says that `read_stata()` does not have support for an encoding argument

Comment: Hi Ricardo, did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue one solution is to use the `pyreadstat` library to load the file (it gives you the option to either load it in a dataframe or dict, see the `output_format` argument):

```
import pyresadstat
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_dta('yourfile.dta', encoding='utf-8)
```

The `meta` variable contains the metadata (variable-label mappings etc). You can even load the unconverted values by setting `apply_value_formats=True` in the `read_dta()` call.